# Can't generate pdf with wicked_pdf in rails ,using search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf, respond-to

Hi everybody I'm trying to use wicked pdf in rails.
Get a pdf based on the object generated by the query, @questions

When downloading the pdf, the query data is lost.
when I visit "/simulators.pdf" it shows me the following error in console

```
Started GET "/simulators.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-01 12:38:19 -0500
Processing by SimulatorsController#index as PDF
Test Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE "tests"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE Test Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE "tests"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @test = Test.find_by(name: params[:test])
  @questions = TestQuestion.joins(:test).where(test_id: @test.id).order('RANDOM()').limit(10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf { render template: 'simulators/pdf', pdf: 'pdf'}
  end
end
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/simulators?test=biology
```

This is url of index view

Can you help me?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi, What I want is to generate a pdf with the objects resulting from the query;
in this case it would be @questions

Comment: When downloading the pdf, the query data is lost.

Comment: When I go to the URL of the pdf, http: // localhost: 3000 / simulators.pdf, the query data was lost

Comment: ´ 
Started GET "/simulators.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-01 12:38:19 -0500
Processing by SimulatorsController#index as PDF
  Test Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE "tests"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Test Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE "tests"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
´

Comment: That's what the console shows, the query is lost.
ok i'm going to edit the question

Comment: You might as well also show (edit question, not in comments) the code where you generate the url.

Comment: You know if there is another way to pass "@question" to the pdf template,
Another doubt, why the query data is lost, in theory should generate the pdf without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because when you ask for the pdf, you need to send the query in the url too

```
 http://localhost:3000/simulators.pdf?test=biology
```

if you don't send the variable in the url, the search that you are doing will be nil, that's the error you are having.

Comment: Hi, It is true what is mentioned, however, the data of the query is lost.
It seems to rerun the query by returning other data, how could this be prevented